# android create object in a bucket on amazon s3 databases

Tags: android

I able to create bucket on amazon s3 databases with the help of amazon demo project.Now i want to create object in bucket.I don't have idea how can i create object.
can anyone provide some example code .can have better idea then please with us.
thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pleas download the AWS SDK for Android from  http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforandroid/

In that SDK please go to samples\S3Uploader folder. There you can find everything about uploading an object(file) to a bucket.

Comment: I can't find such type of folder.I try many times.where is is??Can u make a sample and send me the sample code.please help me,.